Fundamental groups of Calabi-Yau manifolds
This may be a very basic question.
Let $(X,J,g)$ be a compact Kahler manifold, where $J$ is a complex structure and $g$ is a Riemannian metric.
We assume that $(X,J,g)$ is a strict Calabi-Yau $m$-fold, i.e., the holonomy group $\text{Hol}(X)$ of $(X,J,g)$ is $SU(m)$.
Then, it is well-known that its fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$ is finite.
This is obtained from the existence of the Beauville-Bogomolov decomposition.
For example, see proposition 2 of Beauville's paper or Proposition 4.4 of Joyce's paper.
However, I can't understand why the existence of the Beauville-Bogomolov decomposition induces finiteness of the fundamental group.
I would be grateful if you could tell me about the details of this.
Thank you.
Edit 
I have found Remark 11 (page 33) and Theorem 26 (page 34) in this paper.
It seems that they gives the answer for my question.
A little question : for the universal cover $\tilde{X} \rightarrow X$, it is clear that $Hol_0(X) \simeq Hol_0(\tilde{X})$ ?
$Hol_0$ means the identity component of $Hol$.
This claim is used in the proof of Remark 11.

Did you read the proof of Beauville's Proposition 2? Which part do you not understand? Basically, the decomposition theorem implies that the universal cover $X' \to X$ is finite, hence $\pi_1(X)$ is finite.

@red_trumpet  Thank you. I don't understand $(b) \Rightarrow (a) $ part of the proposition.
To prove what you said, where do we need the assumption $Hol(X) =SU(m)$ (not $Hol(X) \subseteq SU(m)$) ?

I have found a paper in Edit. This seems to answer my question.
